# Qt/QML: How to get mobule device battery remaining percentage

Tags: android, linux, mobile, qml, qt5

Is there a way to get battery remaining percentage value on a mobile device (Android and Linux OSs) with Qt5/QML? Or only via system API? Thanks!

Comment: Probably took me less time to google that than it took you to type the question ... does [this](https://falsinsoft.blogspot.com/2017/06/qml-get-android-battery-level-and-status.html) help?

Comment: @tink I asked for cross-platform Qt-framework C++ or QML solution. Previously Qt had solutions for this in QML. And what about Linux?

Comment: What is previous Qt and what was a solution?

Comment: @folibis not sure what version it was, seems some 4.x: https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt-mobility/qml-batteryinfo.html

Comment: I guess that the only way is to implement it by yourself. You can create a c++ extension for QML and so use it in your code. There is several ways, [libacpi](https://evileg.com/en/post/241/) if you on some Linux device or [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30776050/reading-battery-status-on-linux-ubuntu-using-qt) it from a device, using [Android service](https://falsinsoft.blogspot.com/2017/06/qml-get-android-battery-level-and-status.html) etc.

Comment: @folibis thanks much! Could You add above info and links to the answer, please?